# Replicating autoexpanding “concertina” CSS grid row behavior as columns

Tags: css, accessibility, css-grid, translation

[Michelle Barker wrote “Solving a Tricky Layout Problem with CSS Grid”](https://css-irl.info/solving-a-tricky-layout-problem/). Her code works great *vertically*, but I’m struggling to adapt it *horizontally*.

The top/bottom versions successfully scale their text’s grid-row(s) as the viewport narrows (or as you add more text, or the `font-size` increases, etc.). But when tweaking the viewport, text, or `font-size` for the left/right versions… well, I’m not sure how to describe what happens:

| Viewport | Top-aligned | Bottom-aligned | Right-aligned attempt | Left-aligned attempt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wide | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image: Text-positioned at lower-left of media, with more x-axis overlap] |
| Narrow | [image] | [image: Bottom-aligned text at a narrow viewport] | [image: My attempt at right-aligned text at a narrow viewport] | [image] |

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  border: 2px dashed;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

.grid__media {
  background: darkgray;
  font: 2em monospace;
  alignment-baseline: middle;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.grid__text {
  background: rgba(95, 158, 160, 0.7);
}

:root {
  --static-areas: repeat(8, minmax(0, 1fr));
  --autoexpanding-areas: [text-start] 1fr [media-start] auto [text-end] 40px [heading-start] auto [heading-end] 40px auto [media-end];
  --reversed-autoexpanding-areas: [media-start] auto 40px [heading-start] auto [heading-end] 40px [text-start] auto [media-end] 1fr [text-end];
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: var(--autoexpanding-areas);
  grid-template-columns: var(--static-areas);
}

.grid__media {
  grid-row: media;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.grid__text {
  grid-row: text;
  grid-column: span 4/-1;
  align-self: start;
}

.grid--text-bottom {
  grid-template-rows: var(--reversed-autoexpanding-areas);
}

.grid--text-bottom>.grid__text {
  grid-column: 1/span 4;
  align-self: end;
}

.grid--text-left,
.grid--text-right {
  grid-template-rows: var(--static-areas);
  grid-template-columns: var(--autoexpanding-areas);
}

.grid--text-left>.grid__media,
.grid--text-right>.grid__media {
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  grid-column: media;
}

.grid--text-left>.grid__text,
.grid--text-right>.grid__text {
  grid-row: span 4/-1;
  grid-column: text;
  align-self: end;
}

.grid--text-right {
  grid-template-columns: var(--reversed-autoexpanding-areas);
}

.grid--text-right>.grid__text {
  grid-row: 1/span 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <svg class="grid__media"><text x="50%" y="50%">top text</text></svg>
  <div class="grid__text" lang="la">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>

<div class="grid grid--text-bottom">
  <svg class="grid__media"><text x="50%" y="50%">bottom text</text></svg>
  <div class="grid__text" lang="la">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas purus metus, venenatis egestas diam tempus, venenatis ornare sem. Duis maximus erat eget dui aliquet tempor id nec arcu.</div>
</div>

<div class="grid grid--text-left">
  <svg class="grid__media"><text x="50%" y="50%">left text</text></svg>
  <div class="grid__text" lang="la">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>

<div class="grid grid--text-right">
  <svg class="grid__media"><text x="50%" y="50%">right text</text></svg>
  <div class="grid__text" lang="la">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas purus metus, venenatis egestas diam tempus, venenatis ornare sem. Duis maximus erat eget dui aliquet tempor id nec arcu.</div>
</div>
```

Is this is a known difference between CSS’s block and inline axes? Or am I missing some fundamental concept?

### Why I want to accomplish this in the first place

You can see [the real text/artwork/code I’m attempting to use in this CodePen](https://codepen.io/tigt/pen/abRVGqp/e59c8609168b21385ba788125b035872?editors=1100) — I didn’t use them in the above examples since they’re distracting.

I want to overlay speech balloons/other text over comic artwork in a way that adapts to unknown text dimensions. Essentially, I want to give webcomics the inherent flexibility of web pages, for use-cases such as:

- **Translation:** in-browser autotranslate, `translate.google.com`, `bing.com/translator`…
- **Accessibility:** browser/OS text settings, page zoom, font substitution…
- **Responsiveness:** changes from media queries, viewport-based font size…

The idea is to have text start in a desired position and size using CSS Grid overlaps, then as the font changes size/text is translated/etc. it will grow in specific “safe” directions — such as into gutters. If the text grows *enough* into the safe directions, then the gutters/margin/any other spacing around the panel should expand so that the text doesn’t start overlapping and obscuring other panels/text/content. (Also, avoid horizontal scrollbars if at all possible.)

Miscellaneous things I’ve already tried:

- SVG `<text>` (no word wrap and can’t reflow)
- Using SVG but switching back to HTML+CSS with `<foreignObject>` (none of Google Translate, Bing Translate, or builtin browser translations will touch it)
- [ComicA11y’s JavaScript implementation](https://comica11y.humaan.com) (needs JS and it’s not perfect; try translating to German and increasing the font size)
- CSS Shapes (too fragile with just `shape-outside` hacks, needs `shape-inside` to be robust)
- Flexbox with negative margins (can’t properly express how parts should change size)

Comment: So, the problem you want to solve is with the left/right text that doesn't scale to the side in a narrow viewport? What is the desired behavior in this case? If you want the text to scale to the side, at the expense of image becoming smaller? Or do you want it to scale to the side and get a scrollbar? Because now your code does the third option, when no space is left to the side, and image size is fixed, it scales to only possible direction left - vertically.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are attempting to achieve. The result that I see with the provided snippet at any viewport size is similar to the "wide" example.

Comment: @vvv444 I think I’d be happy with either of those first two options, honestly.

Comment: @Tigt After careful reexamination of the question, I agree with TimR - it's a bit unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve.  I propose you reformulate it in two ways: (1) Focus the question on single direction (say "text on the right" case). (2) Provide a list of well defined behavior constraints, like the list in the article you linked. After this question is solved, make a separate question on how to elegantly unite all four solutions into single one if you wish.